# How to remove an option from MUI Datagrid Column Show/Hide panel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

I'm trying to control which columns will show up on the `<GridToolbarColumnsButton/>` component inside of the MUI Datagrid toolbar (see below image)

[image]

**Preferred solution:** 
Use the API thought I haven't found any existing functionality to do this or even any docs for the `<GridToolbarColumnsButton/>` for that matter

**My workaround so far:** 
Use vanilla js to target the row inside of the panel containing the text 'Commodity', add a class to it, and then pass `display:'hide'` for that class in the DataGrid componentsProps.

Problem with it is that since the columns panel isn't mounted at the initial render, it doesn't hide the Commodity option until after I open the panel and then force a re-render.

```
  useEffect( () => {

    var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div .MuiDataGrid-columnsPanelRow')

    for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
      if (divs[i].textContent === 'Commodity') {
        divs[i].classList.add("column-panel-cust");
      }
    }
  })

<DataGridPro
...
   componentsProps={{
            panel: {
              sx: {
                paddingTop: '15px',
                '& .column-panel-cust': {
                  display: 'none',
                },
              },
            },
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could not find an API hook for this but was able to get it working by adding an onBlur to `<GridToolbarColumnsButton onBlur={handleOnBlur}/>` that would run the function:

```
const handleOnBlur = () => {

var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div .MuiDataGrid-columnsPanelRow')

    for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
      if (divs[i].textContent === 'Commodity') {
        divs[i].classList.add("column-panel-cust");
      }
    }
}
```

which added the `column-panel-cust` class to the div with the text commodity, this class's styling was passed in the DataGrid componentsProps:

```
<DataGridPro
...
   componentsProps={{
            panel: {
              sx: {
                paddingTop: '15px',
                '& .column-panel-cust': {
                  display: 'none',
                },
              },
            },
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also go with just some pure css. You just need to target the position of the column. For instance, I am doing the same thing here hiding the Menu from the GridToolbarColumnsButton (last item).

```
 <DataGrid
        columns={columnsDataGrid}
        loading={loadingDataSubcriptions}
        rows={supplierList}
        components={{
          Toolbar: customToolbarSupplier,
        }}
        componentsProps={{
          panel: {
            sx: {
              '& .MuiDataGrid-columnsPanelRow:last-child': {
                display: 'none', 
              },
            },
          },
        }}
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the thread might be old, adding info for anyone that finds this thread...

In MUI DataGrid v6, you can do this in two ways, depending on how you use the Columns Panel.

Option 1: Using the GridToolbarColumnsButton within the toolbar

The GridColumnsPanel, which is the underlying component used by the toolbar button, has a prop called getToggableColumns that takes your columns model for the DataGrid. By default, it takes all the columns passed to the DataGrid "columns" prop. This model can be filtered to remove columns you don't want to show as toggable. You can achieve this by using:

```
function MyCustomToolbar(props: any) {

 return (
  <GridToolbarContainer>
   <GridToolbarColumnsButton/>
   {/* other toolbar items */}
  </GridToolbarContainer>
   );
}

const hiddenFields = ['Commodity', '{hidden column 2}', etc...];

const getTogglableColumns = (columns: any) => {
  return columns
   .filter((column: any) => !hiddenFields.includes(column.field))
   .map((column: any) => column.field);
};
```

hiddenFields defines the columns you want hidden which is then used to filter the DataGrid columns prop to exclude anything listed in the hiddenFields constant.

Once these are added to your code, you will need to apply them to the DataGrid as such:

```
<DataGrid
    {...data}
    slots={{ toolbar: MyCustomToolbar }}
    slotProps={{ columnsPanel: { getTogglableColumns }}}
/>
```

Then when you open the Columns Panel via the toolbar button, the Commodity or any other defined column earlier will be hidden from the user in this panel.

Option 2: Customizing the Grid Columns Panel

If you are using the GridColumnsPanel directly instead of via the toolbar button, such as adding it to a modal popper or another component (my use case), you would still want to define the hiddenColumns and getTogglableColumns constants in Option 1. However, instead of applying them in the DataGrid, you would apply them directly to where you are customizing the GridColumnsPanel component. Now, your component would look like this:

```
<GridColumnsPanel getTogglableColumns={getToggableColumns} {/* other customizations */} />
```

Here, the filtered columns model is passed directly to the component to be used elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can just set your columns by `ColumnPanel` option in `slotProps`.

https://v6.mui.com/x/react-data-grid/column-visibility/#customize-the-list-of-columns-in-panel

```
// stop `id`, `__row_group_by_columns_group__`, and `status` columns to be togglable
const hiddenFields = ['id', '__row_group_by_columns_group__', 'status'];

const getTogglableColumns = (columns: GridColDef[]) => {
  return columns
    .filter((column) => !hiddenFields.includes(column.field))
    .map((column) => column.field);
};

<DataGrid
  slots={{
    toolbar: GridToolbar,
  }}
  slotProps={{
    columnsPanel: {
      getTogglableColumns,
    },
  }}
/>;
```